# Score and Grading System for a mini quiz in Python

Tags: python, system

So I'm testing out a mini quizzing code but I want it to be able to keep score of how many questions the user got correct and incorrect out of 5 while also adding up the score at the end to give a "grade". The code is super simple because I'm just starting out but I'm completely stumped on what to do. Here's what I have so far!

```
def q1(in1,in2):
  print('What is',in1 ,'%' ,in2)
  input()
  if input == in1%in2:
    return 2

def q2(in1,in2):
  print('What is',in1, '*' ,in2)
  input()
  if input == in1*in2:
    return 1
    
def q3(in1,in2):
  print('What is' ,in1 ,'/', in2)
  input()
  if input == in1/in2:
    return 2

def q4(in1,in2):
  print('What is',in1, '**', in2)
  input()
  if input == in1**in2:
    return 2

def q5(in1,in2,in3,in4):
  print('What is' , in1, '-', in2,'*' ,in3 ,'+' ,in4)
  input()
  if input == in1-in2*in3+in4:
    return 3

import random
in1 = random.randint(-10,10)
in2 = random.randint(-10,10)
in3 = random.randint(-10,10)
in4 = random.randint(-10,10)
  


print('Hello, what is your name?')
name = input()

# This part of the script determine whether or not the user is going to take the quiz or not

print(name, 'Would you like to take this quiz? Please type y for yes and n for no')
yesno = input()
if yesno == 'y' :
  print('Great, Here are the questions!')
else:
  exit()


q1(in1,in2)
q2(in1,in2)
q3(in3,in4)
q4(in3,in4)
q5(in1,in2,in3,in4)
#Print score/grade/correct and wrong after here
```

Comment: As a beginner, you got some good code to work with here.  Your question functions (q1-q5) should always return something.  They should return something precise when the user puts in the wrong answer as well as when they put in the right answer.  My guess is that you want to add `return 0` to the bottom of each of those functions.

Comment: Next, you want to do something with the return values of each question function.  You could create a variable like `score` and set it to zero before calling the question functions.  Then add what comes back from each question function to that value.  That will give you the total score.  You can do the same thing for the number of right/wrong answers.  Create a `correct` variable, and increment it by 1 only if a question function returns a value greater than zero.  This would give you the number of questions the user got right.  Hope this helps.  If you wrote this code, you're on your way.

Comment: Are your `return`s in `q1` to `q5` the number of points for each question?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution for your specific question, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Have you tried running it? You should run into a problem with `input` -- you should use `input = input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: @Prune - considering all the garbage questions we get with no though or effort put into them at all, I think this beginner deserves a bit of a break, eh?  He put in quite a bit of effort and is showing it to us, and he is asking somewhat focused questions about what he's trying to do next in his code.  (I take back what I'd put here about running the code.  I guess it runs well enough to seem to function somewhat - I thought it wouldn't run because `input ` isn't defined as a variable.  But it is as a funciton, which is good enough for a math comparison)

Comment: @Steve: the basic question is whether this is easy to search and digest for those coming after.

Comment: @Prune - yeah, I get you.

Comment: I highly apricate the feedback...for the most part, I guess...So far I have added `score = 0` to define that I have some kind of score and replaced `return` at the end of every question with `score = score +1` but at the end of the script when I answer a couple of questions correct and go to print the score using `print str(score)` it just spits back 0 no matter if I got questions right or wrong. Is it because I already have `score = 0` or do I have the adding part to the score wrong?